# How to hide time slots from Google calendar?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

Is it possible to remove certain time slots from Google calendar?

In the evening around 5:30 to 6:00 I'm commuting back from Work to Home. Similarly in the afternoon I have lunch, etc etc.

These time slots take up screen space. In addition I wouldn't want anyone to book my calendar in these slots, or for myself to mistakenly place any event in these times.

I realize I can create dummy events to block up these time, but then the problem is that these show up on my Agenda and clutter the view.

Is it possible to remove such timeslots from my Calendar without filling these up with Dummy Events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing following:

Create another Calendar called Routine and create all such tasks under it. Then turn off notifications from this Calendar and change settings to not show this Calendar on the Agenda.